# Swift: How can I prevent a Index out of range in this instance

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I have an App with a list of players (up to 21) stored in CoreData. When the ViewController loads it shows the players names on buttons in the main screen.

However, I have given the users the ability to delete players, as 21 may be too many for their setup. So they delete and this removes the data from CoreData as expected.

Then they refresh the ViewController and I want to only show buttons for the number of players still in CoreData.

So I used this code :-

```
func reset()
{
    let ksPickButtons = view.subviews.filter{$0 is KSPickButton}
    ksPickButtons.forEach{$0.removeFromSuperview()}

    //sort the player list
    allPlayers.sort()
    playerNo = 0

    //run 2 loops to display the buttons (21 of them)
    for j in 0...2 {
    for i in 0...6 {

            //use the CLASS KSPIckButton to format the buttons
            let buttonOne:UIButton = KSPickButton(frame: CGRect(x: (j + 1) * 35 + (j * 80), y: (i + 5) * 35 + buttonSet, width: 110, height: 30))

            //Add the button to the storyboard
            self.view.addSubview(buttonOne)
            buttonOne.addTarget(self,
                                action: #selector(playerButtons),
                                for: .touchUpInside)
            //assign the tag to the button
            buttonOne.tag = playerNo
            //Give the buttons the players names
            buttonOne.setTitle(allPlayers[playerNo], for: .normal)

        playerNo += 1
    }
    }

    initStart()

}
```

But this line

```
buttonOne.setTitle(allPlayers[playerNo], for: .normal)
```

gives me a fatal error: "Index out of Range" as there are not 21 items any longer, and my loops will increase the playerNo to 21.

I tried "IF" statements but they are ignored when compiling, and the "Index out of Range" still stops the code executing.

How do I identify / stop / skip the error, and just show the number of buttons for the number of players?

Thank you

Comment: `allPlayers` should have `3 * 7 = 21` items. If it doesn't have `21` items then your whole logic is wrong. You are looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Why don't you iterate through the array of players instead of the two nested loops? This will definitively fix the indexing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let isIndexValid = array.indices.contains(index)

 if isIndexValid == true
 {
  buttonOne.setTitle(allPlayers[playerNo], for: .normal)
 } 
  else
 {
  //do nothing
 }
```

This will work.

Comment: Adding an IF statement at the top of the loop didn't work for me, but this works perfectly. Thanks all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement before setting title.

```
if allPlayers.count < playerNo {
  buttonOne.setTitle(allPlayers[playerNo], for: .normal)
}
```

However, this will only prevent the "Index out of Range" and not improve the actual logic. Post whole code so that complete logic is understandable.

Comment: Correct but I would create the `if` condition at the top of loop to prevent creating a button, adding a sub-view etc

Comment: Yes, that's ,such better.